# Skydrive does not appear in Explorer navigation pane in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, onedrive

I used to be able to access SkyDrive through a SkyDrive item in the navigation pane to the left in Explorer, but for some reason now it does not appear, nor are there any share/send to options in the right click context menu.

The only way I can access the SkyDrive is through the ModernUI app which is really annoying to use on a PC with a mouse.

How do I get the SkyDrive Explorer integration back in Windows 8.1?

Comment: If the SkyDrive icon reappears in Windows Explorer after starting the Modern UI SkyDrive app, this could be the same issue as this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/sdfiles-sdsearch/windows-81-skydrive-not-showing-up-in-file/4ba2ccf5-a7b3-4098-94e1-55d1bfad3fe3?page=2. (Unfortunately no solution there until now, either.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few good tutorials to get this done. The one I found that worked for me was [Windows 8.1 get your Skydrive icon back on your taskbar](http://vinny4tech.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/windows-8-1-get-your-skydrive-icon-back-on-your-taskbar/)

It requires creating a new shortcut on the desk top, creating Skydrive shortcut, changing the icon, then you have the ability to pin it to the task bar.

The important point is typing Explorer with a space in step 4.

This was sourced from VINNY4TECH and it got me my skydrive pinned just like I liked it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. It didn't occur to me that my SkyDrive icon was missing from the explorer navigation pane on my Windows 8.1 PC until I needed to access a file from there. The first thing I always do when I notice errors with my PC is to do a restart/reboot. That was exactly what I did to my PC and by the time the computer started after the reboot, the skydrive was back in the explorer nagivation pane. I hope it works for you

Comment: Later when you have the ability to use the comments feature, you could ask if they have tried rebooting as clarification prior to submitting that as a possible answer.